# how to merge two arrays into two objects of one array

Tags: javascript

Array details

```
 array1 = [{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}];
 array2 = [{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}];
```

I need an array result like this...

```
result={array1:[{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}] 
        array2 :[{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}]
       }
```

i have tried concat but i didnt get desired result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you actually want to do is put two arrays into an object, and the name of the array becomes the key in the object?

given:

```
array1 = [...]
array2 = [...]
```

doing this:

```
{ array1, array2 }
Note: this is the same as doing { array1: array1, array2: array2 }
```

should give you:

```
{
 array1: [...],
 array2: [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declaratively do that.

```js
var array1 = [{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}];
var array2 = [{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}];

var result = {array1: array1, array2: array2};

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

That structure is an object that contains 2 arrays:

```js
array1 = [{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}];
array2 = [{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}];
var result = {array1: array1, array2: array2 };
    
console.log (result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a json object with two keys, where two consists of array value.

```
let array1 = [{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}];
let array2 = [{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}];

let result={
        array1 : array1,
        array2 : array2
}
```

output:

```
{
"array1":[{"name":"kumar","id":3},{"name":"jack","id":4},{"name":"jhonny","id":5}],
"array2":[{"name":"simon","id":11},{"name":"david","id":12},{"name":"jack","id":13}]
}
```

if you need it as string ,Convert to string using JSON.stringify(result);

Answer (score 1):

Declare a object of name result and add as many keys as you want like **result.key**

```js
var array1 = [{name:'kumar', id:3},{name:'jack', id:4},{name:'jhonny', id:5}];
var array2 = [{name:'simon', id:11},{name:'david', id:12},{name:'jack', id:13}];

var result = {};
result.array1 = array1;
result.array2 = array2;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add each item to the object you want like so:

```js
var array1 = [{
  name: 'kumar',
  id: 3
}, {
  name: 'jack',
  id: 4
}, {
  name: 'jhonny',
  id: 5
}];
var array2 = [{
  name: 'simon',
  id: 11
}, {
  name: 'david',
  id: 12
}, {
  name: 'jack',
  id: 13
}];

var result = {
  array1,
  array2
};

console.log(result);
```